# Extracting images on .pdf files yields to abnormal vertical strips

Tags: r, file, pdf

```
mat = matrix(1,nrow=501)
```

Let’s compare the image on the window that pops up when calling the function `image(.)` to the image on the .pdf file.

```
image(mat)
```

[image]

```
pdf()
image(mat)
dev.off()
```

[image]

On the .pdf file, the image has vertical strips.

How can I solve this problem? Is the problem even related to R or is it related to the program I am using to read the .pdf (in which case, my question would be off-topic I think).

For info, I am on `MacOS 10.10.2` and the vertical strips are visible both with `Preview` and with `QuickLook`. My R Version is `3.1.2 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the viewer rather than in R. Aliasing errors in pdf viewers are quite common. This is a tiff screen capture of top of a stretched version of that file seen in Preview (OSX 10.7.5)

[image]

And If I stretch it some more:

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, indeed. So There is nothing I can do but trying to open my .pdf with other programs such as Adobe.

Comment: Right. It does appear that the Mac version (at least looking with 9.5.5) of Adobe is free from that error.

Comment: Another option is to create png-files with high resolution. That's what I generally use for posting output in SO questions and answers